# Set button in position "fixed" in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I would like set button on the bottom right corner width fixed position in React Native.

`position: fixed` don't work in React Native and `stickyHeaderIndices` method in ScrollView does not allow to position an element above the others component.

Anyone have already test this feature ?

Comment: could you elaborate more or add a sketch of what you are trying to achieve? Do you just want a button on the lower right corner that sits on top of the scrollview and does not scroll with the scrollview?

Comment: Yes, it's "just" one button in bottom right corner, above multiple components. Sorry, i don't have a sketch :(

Comment: You can use floating button that sits on top of the screen [Help link](https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button). Or if you want to use your custom implementation [use this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135256/floating-action-button-on-react-native)

Comment: Thank you, i go try with this component :)

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={{borderWidth:1,position:'absolute',bottom:0,alignSelf:'flex-end'}}>
           <Button
             title="Press"
             color="#841584"
             accessibilityLabel="Press"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi :) Absolute is not solution with `ScrollView`, the component will not be "fixed" on the bottom

Comment: Do you want button at the bottom right inside scrollview. Please edit your question with some code you are trying and also the screenshot/sketch of your view.

Comment: @s-leg3ndz I have a `View` wrapping my `ScrollView` and the button with `position: 'absolute` outside the `ScrollView` and works as intended.

Answer (score 14):

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
          <Text>body</Text>
    </ScrollView>
    <View><Text>sticky footer</Text></View>
</View>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: those solutions are relevant only for small cases, in real app, in case of multiple nested components this will not work

Comment: Only bottom of view, not bottom of screen.

Answer (score 7):

Just put the component outside of the scrollview and set it with position absolute

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Native Base you can just use the Footer Component