# How to arrange a static button with scrollview in react native that doesn't move?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, scrollview

I am trying to get `scrollview` to work properly with my contacts listed in the entire screen and two statics buttons hovering at the bottom. I can't seem to get them to stick to the bottom (padded slightly from the bottom of the screen). My snack is here:

https://snack.expo.io/@fauslyfox110/testingreferrals

```
ItemScreenTWo.js
```

Here is how it starts:
[image]

When I ask for permissions and open the contacts the names open up and push the buttons down. I would like to keep them stuck at the bottom.

I tried links like these:

[set button in position "fixed" in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188126/set-button-in-position-fixed-in-react-native)

But they haven't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `flex: 1` to your container

App.js

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <InviteScreenTwo /> 
    </View>;
  )
}
```

inviteScreenTwo.js

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    ...
  </View>
```