# Material ui place element at bottom on mobile, desktop, tablet responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am a beginner at layout design and working on a web app for mobile and desktop using `React` and `Material UI`. I need to put app navigation at the bottom. The problem is app navigation is in a different place depending on mobile screen resolution. (iPhone X and iPhone 7). How to place it so that it will be responsive on multiple mobile devices and possibly on tablet and desktop?

[image]

[image]

React and Material UI code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  divContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    height: '99vh',
  },
  root: {},
});

export default function SimpleBottomNavigation() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <Container className={classes.divContainer}>
      <BottomNavigation
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        showLabels
        className={classes.root}
      >
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" icon={<HomeRoundedIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Wishlist" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction
          label="Add"
          icon={<AddCircleOutlineRoundedIcon />}
        />
        <BottomNavigationAction
          label="Notifications"
          icon={<NotificationsIcon />}
        />
        <BottomNavigationAction
          label="Profile"
          icon={<AccountCircleRoundedIcon />}
        />
      </BottomNavigation>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188126/set-button-in-position-fixed-in-react-native) should have the answer you seek.

Comment: @GhostPengy, I think there is no `ScrollView` in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-paper-wor5i?file=/package.json)

create the `root` as below in the `useStyle`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "0px",
    left: "0px",
    right: "0px",
    marginBottom: "0px",
    width: "100vw",
    backgroundColor: "red",
}
});
```

And then assing it as the className to the `BottomNavigation` component:

```
<BottomNavigation
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      showLabels
      className={classes.root}
    >
```

Then, it would be placed at the bottom of the page on different devices.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked great. 1. May I ask you how you achieved this kind of responsiveness in mobile, desktop. Because I have not much experience.

Comment: 2. Another question, how can I write a layout that will work for mobile and desktop? I mean, what kind of approach should I choose? For example, flex, or material UI container.

Comment: Please, could you respond?

Comment: sorry I didn't saw your question. Well, it totally depends on the structure of your project, libraries that are used, and your knowledge about them. If you are comfortable with MUI, I recommend it for handling the responsive views and grid handling.

Comment: Here (https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) there are good links and information about grid handling in material ui